# Why there are empty spots in distribute points with geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Why are there are empty spots even though I maxed the amount? Is there a better way to place multiple objects on another object without overlapping?

[image: Blender screenshot]

The goal is to make something like this. Maybe there is other way than geonodes?
[image: Skull]

Answer (score 1):

It is distributed randomly, that's why some places will never have your particles on them. I am not sure if you can do this as well in Geo nodes because I am still learning them, but in the Particles system, you can distribute particles on faces/vertices. Let's say that this is your object:
[image]

It has 98 vertices, now I go to particle settings and do this:
[image]

This will give you this result:
[image]

You can then change your particles rotation based on normal etc, however, it has one issue... I don't know how your mesh looks like, This way you need to have nice and evenly distributed vertices over your whole mesh in order for it to work. One way if it is not even would be to try remesh on that skull or make your skull manually because you can see that in your reference image these diamonds are making hexagonal pattern

Comment: Thanks for the input but I guess that unfortunately in my case it won't work. My model is a skull model and even after remesh modifier the distances between verticles aren't even and this causes overlapping. :/

Comment: At this point I know that geometry nodes will help me achieve my goal and there is something wrong with the model. I'm trying to fix it. 

https://i.imgur.com/TltVW4S.png - remesh created holes, it got me thinking<br/>

https://i.imgur.com/T5HHWmE.png - after quick sculpt over the place where the holes were